# How to debug Deno CLI using VIsual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, deno

How to debug `Deno CLI` using **Visual Studio 2022**? (not VSCode)

I tried on Visual Studio: `Debug > Attach to process > deno.exe`

but it didn't work, breakpoint dont get hit.

In the Deno [documentation](https://docs.deno.com/runtime/manual/basics/debugging_your_code) it only specifies `VSCode`, isn't possible to debug on **Visual Studio**?

Maybe modifying something in these [options](https://i.imgur.com/MeWcPWD.png)?